# Getting four bits from the right only in a byte using bit shift operations

Tags: c, syntax, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I wanted to try to get only the four bits from the right in a byte by using only bit shift operations but it sometimes worked and sometimes not, but I don't understand why.

Here's an example:

```
unsigned char b = foo; //say foo is 1000 1010
unsigned char temp=0u;

temp |= ((b << 4) >> 4);//I want this to be 00001010
```

PS: I know I can use a `mask=F` and do `temp =(mask&=b)`.

Comment: How is it not working? Can you give an example?

Comment: @EugeneSh. now I see that's what I did in my code too so this isn't why it doesn't work.

Comment: I think `temp = foo & 0xf;` would be the better approach...

Comment: @twalberg no doubt it is, I just want to know more ways to manipulate bits.

Comment: P.S. Why use shift operations at all when `b & 0xF` is faster and more reliable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shift operator only only works on integral types. Using `<<` causes implicit integral promotion, type casting `b` to an `int` and "protecting" the higher bits.

To solve, use `temp = ((unsigned char)(b << 4)) >> 4;`

Comment: My temp is unsigned char in my own code, this doesn't work. For example, the byte `01000001` is assigned itself to temp.

Comment: @kuhaku - You changed the question, I changed the answer :-)

Comment: Yeah that was it. Why does it try to protect the sign bit even though I'm using `unsigned char` in all the types?

Comment: That's simply the way the language is defined. As I wrote, this behavior is known as integral promotion (google it).